# Ways to make a dialogflow chatbot redirect to some website for a particular intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

If a user asks a question to my chatbot eg.what is coding?....then my chatbot should direct it to a wikipedia page about coding.So how can I do it in dialogflow?More specifically if I integrate my dialogflow chatbot with a website then for a particular question....it should direct it to a particular page of my website.Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Channel you are using. 
In most channels you can not force direct the user out of the chat. 
 
You will have to send them a LINK ( most platforms support that ) or you can send them a button or quick reply etc (Depending on the Channel you are using) where the user clicks to open up a webview inside the chat or a browser window